# Why does my listview appear to be empty?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Forms and XAML and I would like to fill a `<ListView>` with appointments. My XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="appointmentsView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding appointmentList}" 
          Grid.Row="1"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.50, 0.2, 1, 0.5"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell> 
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding app1}"></Label>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the code looks like this:

```
public partial class Home : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Appointment> appointmentList = new ObservableCollection<Appointment> ();

    public Employee Tom { get; set; }
    public Appointment app1 { get; set; }

    public Home ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        Tom = new Employee("Tom", "Tommen");
        app1 = new Appointment(new DateTime(), Tom);

        appointmentList.Add(app1);
        appointmentsView.ItemsSource = appointmentList;
    }
```

There is nothing in the list when I debug the application, I would really appreciate it if somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how `Employee` and `Appointment` are defined. For instance:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public DateTime AppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public Employee AppointmentEmployee { get; set; }

    public Appointment(DateTime AppointmentDateTime, Employee AppointmentEmployee)
    {
        this.AppointmentDateTime = AppointmentDateTime;
        this.AppointmentEmployee = AppointmentEmployee;
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Employee(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    override public string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName);
    }
}
```

Then your XAML should be:

```
<ListView x:Name="appointmentsView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding appointmentList}" 
      Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding AppointmentEmployee}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the listview control can display complex objects like you are trying to do (not 100% sure about this though). Something like this:

```
public partial class Home : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Appointment> appointmentList;

    public Home ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        appointmentList = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>()
        {
            new Appointment { Name = "Tom Tommen", AppointmentDate = DateTime.Now }
        };

        appointmentsView.ItemsSource = appointmentList;
    }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @jstreet kinda mentioned, it probably has to do with how you have your `Label` binding to a single item in the `ItemSource`. The `Label`'s `Text` property should be bound to a property that is within a single `Appointment`. In your code above, you are trying to bind the `Label`'s `Text` property to a variable that has nothing to do with the `Appointment` instances that are within the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`.

So if `Appointment` had a `Name` property, and you wanted to display the `Name` of each `Appointment` in your `appointmentList`, you would make your `ListView` and `Label` into:

```
<ListView ItemSource={Binding appointmentList}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell> 
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Or if you wanted to bind the `Labels`'s `Text` property to a property within a specific `Appointment`'s `Employee` (such as the `Employee`'s `Name`, assuming the `Employee` object has a property called `Name` and the `Appointment` object has a property called `Employee`), your label would become:

Answer (score 0):

When you bind something from `Xaml`, it should be inside `BindingContext` of page. Thats call **MVVM** and **Binding** things work with that.

- **Sample Model:**

  class Appointment
  {
      public Employee Employee{get;set;}
      public string Place{get;set;}
      public DateTime time{get;set;}
  }
- **Sample ViewModel:**

  public class TestPageVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      #region  INotifyPropertyChanged interface
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  ```
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion

  private ObservableCollection<Appointment> appointmentList;
  public ObservableCollection<Appointment> AppoitmentList
   {
      get{return appointmentList;}
      set
      {
          appointmentList = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("AppoitmentList");
      }
   }
   //ctor

   public TestPageVM()
   {
      appointmentList = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>();
      AppoitmentList.Add(new Appointment(){
          Employee = new Employee("Johm Doe"),
          Place = "Houston",
          DateTime = DateTime.Now
      });
   }
  ```

  }
- **Sample View Class Initialization**:

  public partial class Home : ContentPage
  {
      public Home ()
      {
          InitializeComponent ();
          this.BindingContext = new TestPageVM();
      }
  }

-Xaml Usage:

```
<ListView x:Name="appointmentsView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AppoitmentList}" 
          Grid.Row="1"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.50, 0.2, 1, 0.5"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell> 
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Employee.Name}"/>
                    <!--can also show place of appointment like: <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Place}"/> -->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Just a quick clarification, your statement about binding context in a XAML page is correct, but from within a `ListView`'s `DataTemplate`, the binding context becomes what ever you bind the `ListView`'s `ItemSource` to. So the `ContentPage`'s `BindingContext` will be used within the `ListView`'s `ItemSource`, but it will not be used within the `ListViews`'s `DataTemplate`.